# unknown blob on docker push to gcp

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I have a CI/CD build system running on GCP cloud build.
It sporadically fails upon dock push with error: "unknown blob" (see below).
Rerunning the failed job ends with a success result.

The CI/CD is a Google CloudBuild job, that runs a shell script.
The shell script runs docker build, and then docker push, so the built image is available locally after the build.

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t gcr.io/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/test:latest-stage1
docker push gcr.io/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/test:latest-stage1
```

Any ideas?
Maybe I can add some additional commands to print some debug info for next time it happens?

```
Pushing image gcr.io/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/test:latest-stage1
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/XXX/YYY/ZZZ/test]
4eed37762d61: Preparing
a68d95ff11ea: Preparing
dddcf18e7786: Preparing
e8c437b49d31: Preparing
dea41e2ed72f: Preparing
b660dabbb08d: Preparing
3434e68efd32: Preparing
efc45381b778: Preparing
0902cfca6c4f: Preparing
66f4f21514da: Preparing
9e27e8abe53b: Preparing
7b5ae180667a: Preparing
613ab28cf833: Preparing
bed676ceab7a: Preparing
6398d5cccd2c: Preparing
0b0f2f2f5279: Preparing
b660dabbb08d: Waiting
3434e68efd32: Waiting
efc45381b778: Waiting
0902cfca6c4f: Waiting
66f4f21514da: Waiting
9e27e8abe53b: Waiting
7b5ae180667a: Waiting
613ab28cf833: Waiting
bed676ceab7a: Waiting
6398d5cccd2c: Waiting
0b0f2f2f5279: Waiting
dea41e2ed72f: Layer already exists
b660dabbb08d: Layer already exists
3434e68efd32: Layer already exists
efc45381b778: Layer already exists
0902cfca6c4f: Layer already exists
66f4f21514da: Layer already exists
9e27e8abe53b: Layer already exists
a68d95ff11ea: Pushed
613ab28cf833: Layer already exists
7b5ae180667a: Layer already exists
6398d5cccd2c: Layer already exists
bed676ceab7a: Layer already exists
0b0f2f2f5279: Layer already exists
4eed37762d61: Pushed
dddcf18e7786: Pushed
unknown blob
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details of the CI/CD system configured along with steps to replicate the issue? FYI, the `unknown blob` error appears when the `docker push` command fails to find out parts of the image that it intends to push.

Comment: I've added more details about the build. Kindly let me know if anything else might be useful.

Comment: Useful information you need to include are the specific shell scripts you are currently using to build your Docker image, in addition to any [available logs](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/store-manage-build-logs#viewing_build_logs) in Cloud Build. These details are what would help anyone pinpoint the potential causes of the issue. For a guide of what details to provide, you can review this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've added a build script example

Comment: Since this problem seems to happen intermittently and without any apparent pattern, you can file an issue in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for GCP using [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187156&template=1163179&pli=1) submission form, or open a [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/procedures).

Comment: this might be useful: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-private/3.2.x?topic=console-cannot-push-new-images-cloud-private